# Using `rules_scala` + Bazel, how to bundle transitive JARs that are exported as part of a `scala_library` target, without going full `_deploy.jar`?

Tags: scala, bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-java, bazel-aspect

Let's say I have a library such as:

```
scala_library(
    name = "my_favorite_scala_library",
    srcs = glob(["*.scala"]),
    exports = [
        "A",
        "B",
    ],
    deps = [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D",
    ],
)
```

`bazel build //path/to/my/library:my_favorite_scala_library` builds a "skinny" JAR as expected and doesn't package in any dependencies or exports.

Building a `_deploy.jar` will package in all transitive dependencies.

Is there a simple way to have some middle ground where I can build a JAR that will package in only the main source AND any exports, either using the `exports` functionality or some other Bazel functionality that I may be overlooking? I'm open to both some custom invocation of a `bazel build` command or some field/functionality on the rule definitions that I may not be aware of.

Comment: One thing which I don't want to speculate too much on in the main post, but will add as a comment here, is that I'm unsure whether `runtime_deps` from `java_library` and `scala_library` is what I'm looking for.